# exchange 2007 with two accepted domains, send mail

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2007

in my exchange server 2007 config, i have two accepted domains. my company runs two websites which sells similar items, however they do not want customers to know that websites are related in any way. there are only around 5 users that have email addresses on the secondary domain, everyone else uses the primary

i'll start by explaining how this was setup until i got a hold of it:
a way which i don't understand all the details. Anything that is sent to the @secondarydomain.com is forwarded to an external gmail account which that employee uses to reply to the customer (?) idk  it was explained that this was configured by using contact forwarding names. again idk, dont even really care how this was set up.

i'm setting it up like this:
sussexjewelers is an accepted domain, the smtp address for the @secondarydomain is included in the users mailbox using the email addresses tab. i have a transport rule that checks the message header to address for the text pattern @secondarydomain and preappends the subject with "Secondary Domain Email **" so they can tell where the email was from.

how can i send mail from the secondary domain? 
in outlook, if they reply, the from address remains the primary domain.

do i have to set them up a secondary mailbox for the @secondarydomain?

not sure how to accomplish this. i just want to get rid of the entire gmail forwarding setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've found the reason for the forwarding. Exchange considers one address to be canonical for users, and that's the Reply address, the bolded one in the list. Attempts to use other addresses will get rewritten to be the Reply address.

There is one instance where this will NOT happen, though. If you have an Edge server, and configure that Edge server to allow relays from your local LAN, people can use Thunderbird to send email through that Edge server using the non-canonical address. They'll still fetch it from the Client Access server as normal, but the SMTP server needs to be an Edge server that allows email relaying from their IP.

Comment: By setting the "Set as Reply" on the address you wish for the users to send as, their outbound mail will show up from that address. Are you asking for a way to have the users select on-the-fly which address they want to send as? – ewwhite       @sys im guessing this is not possible then? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the user mailbox management console within Exchange, you need to choose the user and set their default Reply from address using the "Set as Reply" button under the E-Mail Addresses Tab. The preferred address will be **BOLDED**.

Comment: right. most of there emails will be to @primarydomain.com, i want the primary to be the default reply from address. but the @secondarydomain.com is still routed to there mailbox. how can i have them reply using the @secondarydomain.com ?

Comment: By setting the "Set as Reply" on the address you wish for the users to send as, their outbound mail will show up from that address. Are you asking for a way to have the users select on-the-fly which address they want to send as?

Comment: yeah, but reading below i'm guessing that you can not do this?